# What is the best way to save CRM data, when designing a CRM using ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, crm, quickbooks

I'm a newbie to ASP.NET MVC. I've been learning MVC 3 for the past couple months and at my job I have to design a CRM system using MVC 3.

In all MVC 3 tutorials, they use MS SQL Compact Edition.

In the CRM project, I have to import Products table from the QB Database and populate that into the CRM.

Keeping in mind, the CRM has to use the QB database and import the products table and 
Should I save the CRM data in SQL CE or should I use SQL Server to save all the CRM data as well as the QB data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC 3 is entirely decoupled from the data layer.. The reason you'll have seen most tutorials coupling it with SQL Compact is because most web application tend to need a database of some sorts to be functional and SQL Compact is one of the simplest options when focus should really be on MVC itself.

As far as MVC, you need some way of making data available to the controller and ultimately the view.. you don't even have to use the entity framework (which I guess most examples use for simplicity), however, if you do want to use the entity framework, it looks like you can query quickbooks directly by using [this](http://www.rssbus.com/kb/help/RQR1-A/pg_linqtoef.rst)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you should implement next logic:

1. Retrieve needed data from QuickBooks. Here you can use any kind of paid tools like RssBus QuickBooks Data Provider mentioned above, but you are still free to do it using QuickBooks SDK directly (QBXML or QBFC), it is not so hard.
2. Convert received data to format applicable to your Products table structure.
3. Perform data export using LINQ to SQL or whatever you want. It is completely up to you which edition of MS SQL Server to use and depends only on complexity of functionality that you need from it.